Counter variable for Artillery using Playwright
For each iteration of my Artillery test, I need to create a post with a counter for the title. I cannot use randomString or something like this as it needs to be like "Test 1", "Test 2", etc each time. I cannot seem to figure it out with Artillery and Playwright.
Can anyone help? :)
